# Error: While launching an instance from Launch Templates. "value () for parameter groupid is invalid. the value cannot be empty"

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am getting the error

```
value () for parameter groupid is invalid. the value cannot be empty
```

while launching an EC2 instance from the Launch template.

When it was initially created from templates it was working fine. I have deleted all the templates and created new templates with new SG and key pairs.

With new templates, I am getting this error. I have check-in my CloudFormation but I didn't create any templates.

Comment: its far easier to understand how things need to be if you first do all the steps manually ... then you can answer your own question like this ... if possible spin up one instance using manual steps so you know its working as intended ... then spin up a different ec2 instance to execute your automation on ... then when automation breaks you can eyeball the working manually installed instance with the currently broken auto instance and see where they differ ... jumping straight into using abstractions without a firm understanding of the underlying basics is a high risk high reward approach

Comment: another approach is to always build automation which creates along with matching automation which destroys ... then on errors just run the destroy then you know you are starting your automation from scratch ... my guess is you have lingering aws items created from previous failed automation run

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing same problem.I deleted my key pairs and relaunched a new ec2 instance in another zone i.e. ohio. It worked for me.